# "Make it so!" - where does it come from, how does it "feel" for native speakers?

Tags: etymology, catch-phrases

The catchphrase from Star Trek captain Jean-Luc Picard "Make it so!" was first used in "Encounter At Farpoint" (28 September 1987)  and thereafter  in many episodes and films, instructing a crew member to execute an order.

**My question**
Where does this phrase come from? Was it "invented" for Star Trek? What are the associations for native speakers, when they hear it (apart from Star Trek ;-) Does it feel strange or like Old English?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It had a specific nautical meaning in the 19th century. From the OED:

> **I. 35. †f.** *Naut.* In the imperative phrase ***make it so***, by which the commander of a vessel instructs that the time reported to him (e.g. the end of a watch and *spec.* noon, when sights are taken to determine what was formerly the start of a ship's day) is relayed to the crew (see quots. 1826   and 1867). Hence (occas.): to mark (a time of day, etc.) formally in this way. Also in extended use. *Obs.*
>
> 1826   *Let.* 14 Mar. in G. Jones *Sketches Naval Life* (1829) I. 101   Eight bells are now reported to the quarter-master, and by him, to the officer of the deck; who answers, ‘make it so’; and sends a midshipman, to inform the captain, that it is meridian. The bell is struck; and two long successive pipes, from the boatswain and his mates, are the signal, that all work is to cease.

Also:

> **V.** To behave, act, or move (in a specified way).
>
> †**54.** *trans.*
>
> **a.**  [Probably after the same Latin idiom as sense 55a.] ***to make it***   (with adverb or adverb phrase of manner): to act, behave. ***make it so***: see also sense 35f. *Obs.*
>
> eOE   King Ælfred tr. Gregory *Pastoral Care* (Tiber.) (Junius transcript) xvi. 98   Ðeah he [sc. Paul] upaðened wære on his modes scearpnesse, ne forhogode he ðæt he hit eft gecirde to ðæm flæsclican burcotum, & gestihtode hu men sceoldon ðærinne hit macian.
>
> [...]
>
> a1586   *Peblis to Play* in W. A. Craigie M*aitland Folio MS* (1919) I. 178   Quhat neidis ȝow to maik it sua?

I found an example earlier than the OED's 1826 of the naval command. It appears in correspondance in *[The Naval Chronicle, For 1808: Containing a General and Biographical History of The Royal Navy of th United Kingdom; With a Variety of Original Papers on Nautical Subjects Volume XX (From July to December)](http://archive.org/stream/navalchronicleco20londiala#page/203/mode/1up)*:

> THE grand mechanism of naval discipline (if I may be allowed 
>   the expression), consists in the various gradations which 
>   take place, from the monarch who delegates his power to the 
>   Admiralty, to the lowest ship-boy. [...] This 
>   rule is in general well supported in our ships of war, and it has 
>   amused, if not excited the ridicule of some landmen who have observed its various stages 
>   in trifling instances. Thus, a centinel 
>   informs the quarter-master, that "it is twelve o'clock;" the 
>   quarter-master the mate ; the mate the lieutenant; the lieutenant 
>   the captain ; the captain the admiral ; and then the order to ring 
>   the bell, or, as it is usually, though absurdly, expressed, ***make it so***, 
>   returns back through the same number of persons, before the 
>   important command can be given to, and executed by the cook's 
>   mate.

Comment: Presumably a comment might be worthwhile about how starships in the *Enterprise* series are seen as being in the tradition of the ocean-going sailing ships which the OED I.35.f describes, complete with a ship's wheel on the observation deck.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed very helpful! Now for the "feel": I guess most people are not experts in 19th century nautical lingo, so how does this phrase "feel" to a modern native speaker?

Comment: There is nothing *exclusively* nautical about it, nor idiomatic: it is simply the imperative form of a standard expression. For example, Shakespeare wrote: "there is nothing either good or bad, but thinking **makes it so**".

Comment: @vonjd I wouldn't think that a native speaker would ever misunderstand this phrase but it would likely seem a bit pretentious if it was used seriously.  That being said, I think I may start using this with all my students :)

Comment: I was in the US Marine Corps. At boot-camp, when we were given an order, and the Drill Instructor would say "Do it now!" so that it was well understood that the command was meant for immediate execution. That set a mindset for me so that when I hear "Make it so" it strikes me as "Do it now." Knowing there is a strong nautical influence in the traditions of Starfleet, I always thought this was their equivelent.

Comment: I would like to advert to the fact that this seems to be a very old Germanic term. In modern days Swiss German we still use the very same wording for the very same meaning as the English term ("Mach's so" [Sg.] / "Machet's so" [Pl.] = "Make it so").

Answer (score 0):

There is already an accepted answer, but there was some discussion in the comments of the "feel" to modern English speakers, and I thought it was worth covering that in a more permanent answer.

The expression is distinctive and unusual, and sounds quite formal. I would say maybe it sounds a little old-fashioned, but not like something out of Shakespeare or anything. Most people aren't aware that British captains used to say it in the 1820's, but everyone would believe that's the kind of thing one of those captains might say.

I think it worked as a catch phrase because it is so much crisper than something like "OK, go ahead and do that, then."

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to hear the phrase used in an historical drama film a couple of years ago. I think it was said by Charlton Heston, so it might have been in [*Antony and Cleopatra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antony_and_Cleopatra_(1972_film)). It was definitely a film of that period, quite well known, and made around the 1960s or 1970s.

I can’t remember what the film was; it was just on the TV in the background behind me and I didn’t know any [*Star Trek: The Next Generation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) fans to mention it to, so I forgot it. It might even have been a Biblical epic movie.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yul Brynner, as Pharaoh in _The Ten Commandments_ (1956), has the memorable lines 'So let it be written. So let it be done.'